# Is it possible to run the Chromium Browser on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromium

Since you should be able to build Chromium browser on any reasonably modern Linux distribution, can we assume that you should be able to build it onto Android ?

Comment: So, does that mean that it is possible, but just need to explicitly install the libs?  Or does it take more than that ?

Comment: Who are you asking? Me, I already said *no*, it's not possible. (Without a lot of effort, at least.)

Comment: Looks like Chromium is coming to Android: http://codereview.chromium.org/8008026

Comment: Source code is available : http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code#TOC-Android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Android is not exactly a Linux distribution. It's based on a Linux kernel, but it doesn't include an X server nor other [dependencies](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructionsPrerequisites) for building Chromium on Linux.

However the Android Browser is also based on WebKit and includes the V8 JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 3):

You can now run Chrome on Android:

http://code.google.com/chrome/mobile/

It's only available on some countries and only on Android 4.0+.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Actually it was the other way around. The Android web browser serve as [startup for the google chrome browser](http://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/small_12.html)

It is possible, there would be tons of restrictions.

According to this [source](http://androidcommunity.com/google-chrome-coming-to-android-20080903/) ( sept 2008 )

> *Google co-founder, Sergey Brin revealed a few interesting tidbits about the Chrome/Android connection*

So, that was actually initially planned, but haven't quite happened yet.  The two team ( Android browser and Chrome ) are very busy getting their own product ready.

It may be developed eventually by the open source community, but don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have many of the same libs that you'd find in a modern Linux distribution, so I would suspect that it would take a lot of re-engineering to make it happen.  Maybe it's possible, but I would be very surprised.

Answer (score 0):

well you can run chrome on you android devices... and there should not be much problem with that

http://www.google.co.in/intl/en/chrome/browser/mobile/android.html

They are claiming about Chrome for Android devices :) Simple find for me.

About review following is that...[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Android 4.4 and above, there's a free and open-source app [getChromium](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.anddevw.getchromium) that installs/updates the Chromium browser on Android.

FULL DISCLOSURE: I put together getChromium as an open-source means of getting builds directly from Google's repository over here: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/Android.